# how to remove all OU from AD via powershell

Tags: powershell

I am testing powershell with active directory,
have created list of OU in particular domain, but unable to remove all the OU from AD, Want to remove all OU except built in from AD
below is the script i am using, but it is giving access denied-
using administrator id

```
Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -Filter {Name -notlike "Domain Controllers"} -SearchBase (Get-ADDomain).Distinguishedname -SearchScope OneLevel | Remove-ADOrganizationalUnit -Recursive -Confirm:$false
```

Comment: This might be a better fit for ServerFault.

Comment: I had one more query that i have asked in serverfault, how do i move this question over there

Answer (score 0):

OU's are protected by default, you have to remove that flag before deleting:

```
Set-ADObject -ProtectedFromAccidentalDeletion $false
```